# jQuery animate sprite on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm just trying to work out if I could achieve something where I have a paint mark, that currently is used as a background image below a nav list item.

Is it possible to animate a secondary `div` that's overlapped at the bottom of the `li` that creates a reveal effect on the background image so that it looks as if the image is appear from left to right, until the line is fully shown? Sort of like a growing image as you hover.

Comment: javascript can do the dishes if you throw enough resources at it

Comment: you can do the animation with an animated background gif on hover, or you could use css3 (possibly) to achieve the desired effect using background position or width. it really depends on what effect your trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You could also give a try to mine SpriteOnHover jquery plugin.

It has some parameters you could work with and it's lightweight so it's maybe worth it. You can get it here http://apolinariopassos.com.br/dev/sprite-on-hover-jquery-plugin/

The usage is `$('#yourSprite').spriteOnHover();` 
This will make the plugin work this the default parameters, which points to this:

```
$('#yourSprite').spriteOnHover({fps:30, orientation:"horizontal", rewind: true, loop: false, autostart:false;repeat:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` properties with jQuery.

I don't have any code from you to show you but here is an example.

```
$('#element-to-animate').animate({
    'background-position-x': '10%',
    'background-position-y': '20%'
}, 1500, 'linear');
```